# Consuming web api response is in encrpyted form but that response convert in json formate issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkT7X.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCDlq.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwp4t.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teQX7.png)

```
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<polygon>>(EmpResponse);
```

json converting at time error rasing Could not cast or convert from `System.String` to `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Api.Models.polygon].`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teQX7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with  EMPResponse JSON format that's why you are getting convertion error.
please check your EMPResponse JSON is containing List or Object.
Also share your JSON Response.